# Like Operator is not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in which I am creating a dynamic query for my statement. But I don't know what mistake I am doing in dynamic query part of the stored procedure, in which I am using the LIKE operator. Below is my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usptestSearchEmployee 
@Name varchar(50)= null,
@EmpNumber varchar(50)=null,
@Location Varchar(50)=null,
@position varchar(50)=null,
@partialmatch bit ,
@partialmatch2 bit,
@partialmatch3 bit 

AS
BEGIN

declare @wheresql varchar(max)
if (@Name is not null)
BEGIN
if(@partialmatch=1)
 set @wheresql=' where EmpName like ''%'' '+  @Name 
else
  set @wheresql=' where EmpName = '+@Name
END
PRINT @wheresql
set @wheresql='select * from employee ' +@wheresql
  select @wheresql
END
```

The query in the stored procedure is creating like this `select * from employee  where EmpName like '%' oo`  where i am doing mistake . 
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `like` should look like this: `select * from employee where EmpName like '%oo'`

so change this line:

```
set @wheresql=' where EmpName like ''%'' '+  @Name
```

to

```
set @wheresql=' where EmpName like ''%'+  @Name + ''''
```

As pointed out by @IanNelson, you have also made a mistake of trying to use the `SELECT` keyword with a string containing sql. You need to use either [`EXEC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

```
EXEC(@wheresql)
```

or [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

```
sp_executesql @wheresql
```

Comment: you are sure your answer is ok because it is showing error in sql server editor?

Comment: the same solution I have provided previously and you have made negative marking for it.Why? After that I have edited my answer.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya - Your *original* answer was just a wall of updated code without any explanation as to *what you had changed*. The same answer that I removed my -1 when you updated it!

Comment: still your answer is not proper it not making proper statement. My answer is tested with the SQL server editor and its work perfect. In your answer (') is generated more.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya - get over it already. Sheesh. Now ive tested it in QA. happy?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the changes noted by @jamiec, I think you also need to

```
EXEC(@wheresql)
```

rather than

```
SELECT @wheresql
```

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

You have ***Unclosed quotation mark*** in your Query. Try like below.

*Change the following Query*

**FROM**

```
 if(@partialmatch=1)
 set @wheresql=' where EmpName like ''%'' '+  @Name 
 else
  set @wheresql=' where EmpName = '+@Name
 END
 PRINT @wheresql
 set @wheresql='select * from employee ' +@wheresql
  select @wheresql
```

**TO**

```
if(@partialmatch=1)
 set @wheresql=' where EmpName like ''%'+  @Name + ''''
else
  set @wheresql=' where EmpName = ''' + @Name + +''''
END
PRINT @wheresql
set @wheresql='select * from employee ' +@wheresql
EXEC(@wheresql)
```